# If $f$ is measurable, then support of $f$ is measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

Could someone please check if I'm saying something that make sense? I am trying to check the following:

> If $f$ is a measurable function, then $\text{supp}(f)$ is measurable set?

Is it simply because, if we consider $E_1 = (0,\infty)$ and $E_2 = (-\infty,0)$, since they are open, they are measurable. So their union $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$ is measurable as well. Since $f$ is measurable, then the preimage $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}-\{0\})$ is measurable. But the preimage is just the support?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually for technical reasons we define the support to be the *closure* of the complement of the preimage of zero, i.e. $\overline{f^{-1}(\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \})}$. This will be measurable by virtue of being closed, though.

That said, $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \})$ itself is also measurable.